# how can I view shading in texture paint mode?

Tags: texture-painting

The object I am trying to paint on is showing up as solid white and I am unable to see any edges or detail of the object. Is there a way to turn on shading whilst previewing the solid image texture?

[image: object solid white in texture paint]

Comment: Are you plugged into an emission shader? I have my object set the same in viewport, and only way I come up with 'no shadow' in mat preview is to use emission.

Answer (score 2):

You're in material preview mode. Switch to solid view. (Circles in the top right corner. One to the left of your current selected one.)

[image]